# semiample of canonical bundle in a smooth family (Campana's proof)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, deformation-theory

The following lemma is due to Campana, [The class $\mathcal  C$ is not stable by small deformations](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01459236)

> Let $\mathcal X\rightarrow \Delta$ be a smooth family, if $K_{X_0}$ is nef and big, then so is every $K_{X_t}$ for $t$ sufficiently small.

Here is the step. Invoking Kawamata-Viehweg vanishing theorem, one has
$$H^i(X_0,NK_{X_0})=0$$
for $N\geq 2$. Then the similarly higher cohomology vanishing holds for $K_{X_t}$ by Grauert direct image theorem.
Therefore,
$$h^0(X_t,NK_{X_t})=h^0(X_0,NK_{X_0})\,\,\,\,\,\,(*)$$ for $N\geq 2$ thanks to deformation invariance of Euler characteristic.
Also, the base point free theorem tells us that
$|NK_{X_0}|$ is globally generated for sufficiently big $N$.

Then the author claims that this fact combines (*) can infer that
$|NK_{X_s}|$ is also globally generated for sufficiently big $N$ (this will imply the nefness of $X_t$ then).
Why this holds? How the size of global sections determine the base locus with respect to $X_t$ in our setting?

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be of interest to you : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/321189/is-being-of-general-type-stable-under-generization

Comment: Dear @AriyanJavanpeykar, so many thanks for your kind and useful information!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f:X\rightarrow \Delta $ be your family. $\ (*)$ implies that $f_*K_{X/\Delta }^{N}$ is a vector bundle on $\Delta $, with fiber $H^0(X_t, K_{X_t}^N)$ at $t\in\Delta$. The canonical homomorphism $\ f^*f_*K_{X/\Delta }^{N}\rightarrow K_{X/\Delta }^{N}$ is surjective on $X_0$ by hypothesis, hence also on $X_t$ for small $t$.